# how to install wireless driver for my old laptop hp dv6 1340ej

Tags: wireless, drivers, laptop, hp, dv6

its connected to the internet and all fine but its very and slow and I've tried almost everything with some terminal commands and I got some improve but still slow compared to the internet win I login in windows 7 where I have the wireless driver installed I think I need to know my wireless hardware driver for my specific laptop and find the driver for it but can't find it anyone can help ?

here is my device details:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0084]

command : lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: @chili555 this is my wireless device 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0084]
thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pinged Google directly, going through the DNS nameserver provided by your internet service provider, you got an average round trip time of 574 ms. When you pinged by number, thereby bypassing the DNS nameserver provided by your internet service provider, the average was 73 ms. That's not a great time, but obviously a huge improvement over 574 ms. I suggest you right-click the Network Manager icon and edit connections, select IPv4 wireless and change the method from Automatic (DHCP) to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only. Fill in the DNS nameservers as here: http://cache.gawkerassets.com/assets/images/lifehacker/2009/12/ubuntu_dns.jpg

Save and close. Now is it improved?

Comment: my led wireless indicator on my laptop have tow color when its orange its off when its blue its ON, so when I logged in windows 7 the indicator is always on I mean its stable on blue color but in ubuntu its flash between the tow colors therefore I think its about the driver for the hp wireless built in hardwere which I got in my windows 7 but in ubuntu I can't found it

Comment: I did what you explained in your answer and I got this results : `~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8 | grep mdev.
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 78.587/82.592/85.692/2.979 ms
~$ ping -c3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes icmp_req=2 ttl=58 time=17.9 ms
64 bytes icmp_req=3 ttl=58 time=17.9 ms
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.901/18.315/19.071/0.535 ms`

Comment: "min/avg/max/mdev = 17.901/18.315/19.071/0.535 ms" Awesome times! Are we all set? If you want to work on the LED, I think that's a separate question for you to ask.

Comment: no its okay not bad result at all thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

The driver for your device is quite well known to have problems with N speeds from the router. As a temporary experiment, let's disable it and see if the speeds improve. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: yes there is improvement I can see it , but I need more there is more is there a like driver for that ..?

Comment: A 'like driver'? The driver iwlwifi is the only working driver for your device. Getting optimal speeds usually involves fine-tuning settings in the driver, like 11n_disable and getting the best settings in the router. I suggest WPA2 not the tricky WPA and WPA2 mixed mode. I suggest AES encryption and not TKIP. You might also set the router to channel 1 or 11 to see if there is improvement. What kind of ping times are you getting? ping -c3 www.google.com

Comment: `PING www.google.com (ip) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham02s11-in-f18.1e100.net (ip): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=573 ms
64 bytes from ham02s11-in-f18.1e100.net (ip): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=576 ms
64 bytes from ham02s11-in-f18.1e100.net (ip): icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=574 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2067ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 573.902/574.946/576.315/1.337 ms`

Comment: Pretty poor times! Are ping times bypassing your DNS similar? ping -c3 8.8.8.8 | grep mdev. Are times better with ethernet?

Comment: `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 72.297/73.088/74.177/0.795 ms` is it bad 2 ?